# Custom initialization of Subview in iOS gicing error

Tags: ios, uiview

I am facing problem in custom initialization of my subview class the method somewhat look like this
      my sub view .h file lloks like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface mysubview : UIView

@property(nonatomic,strong)UIButton *mybutton;

@end
```

ViewController.m file

```
-(id)initWithbutton:(CGRect)frame color:(UIColor*)mycolor
{
    NSLog(@"Into the initializer");
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        mybutton = [[UIButton     alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width/2,frame.size.height/2,20,20)];
        [mybutton setTitle:@"b" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [mybutton setTitle:@"b" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        self.backgroundColor = mycolor;
        [self addSubview:mybutton];

    }
    return self;
}
```

and in my viewcontroller i am calling it as

```
p_subview1 = [[mysubview alloc] initWithbutton:CGRectMake(10,10,70,70) color:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

but during compilation i am getting error no visible interface in my subview class has this method plz consider if i am doing something silly here I am new to iphone development.

Comment: mysubview is a class of `UIView` or `UIButton`?

Comment: Do you import the .h file for your custom view class in your view controller? Is the name correct? Is it `initWithButton:color:` or `initWithbutton:color:`? Note the `b` versus `B`.

Comment: yes I have checked it is correct its initWithbutton:color:

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    p_subview1 = [[mysubview alloc]initWithbutton:CGRectMake(10,10,70,70) color:[UIColor blueColor]];
    
    
    [self.view addSubview:p_subview1];
}

Comment: Why don't you copy and paste the exact and complete error message. Also update your question with the .h file of your custom subview class. Use real names to avoid typos in your question.

Comment: ViewController.m:23:19: No visible @interface for 'mysubview' declares the selector 'initWithbutton:color:'

Comment: Your .h file is the problem. You don't have a declaration for the `initWithbutton:color:` method in the .h file.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong as per my knowledge we don't require method declaration in .h in obj c

Comment: You are incorrect. If another class needs to use a public method of another class, the .h of the class needs to list its public methods. If you were correct you wouldn't be having this issue.

Comment: @user2007454 did u find the solution ... r u there?

Comment: yes i am here,need to check right now away from my mac

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

interface ButtonView : UIView

property(nonatomic,strong)UIButton *mybutton;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame  color:(UIColor*)mycolor;

Comment: add this in .h file of the uiview subclass

Comment: for refferenece example here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xmhc5lecp23rv1d/SampleIOS7tries.zip

Comment: sure I will and update you all as soon as I get close to my mac, thanks for all your response

Comment: Thanks all its finally working.